# Enabling OPcache

Tags: php, server, lamp

My webserver uses PHP 5.6.31. I verified this using `phpinfo();`

I'm trying to use OPcache which was built into PHP 5.5+

I don't see any references to OP code caching in phpinfo, so I think it might be disabled.

I created my **php.ini** file with:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption=64
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=7963
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.enable=1
```

I also added **post_max_size = 6M (it was defaulting to 8M)** just so I could verify my changes were going into effect.

I see the post max size change being implemented, but I'm still not seeing anything for OPcache in phpinfo. What am I doing wrong?

Is there a way to see if the hosting company didn't compile PHP with OPcache? And if they excluded it, is it possible to still use it without having to recompile it? Similar to how you could have used it prior to version 5.5

Comment: If you run a page with `phpinfo();` can you check the php.ini file it's picking up.  I would have thought there was an existing one you should edit rather than creating a new one.

Comment: I thought there would have been one too, but there wasn't. I'm running a page with phpinfo(); as mentioned above and other things are picking up, just nothing about OPcache.